# Linux is there any way to set IP address permanently using C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, linux, qt

I reffered many links to change IP address using C/C++. But I found that its only changing the setting temporary (untill the next reboot) and Once the system is rebooted , the all settings are gone.

I referred below links to achieve it.

[Qt: Setting the IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619652/qt-setting-the-ip)

[Set IP address using SIOCSIFADDR ioctl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308090/set-ip-address-using-siocsifaddr-ioctl)

etc. but ended up with temporary settings (remains untill the next reboot)

Is there any way to change the settings permanently through C/C++ ?????

Please direct me to the right path.

Comment: Yes: change the system configuration. Try on a Linux forum (e.g. where/how the settings are stored and applied). Off Topic.

Comment: Try unix.stackexchange.com or similar with your specific distro. For example, config in Debian/Ubuntu lives in /etc/network/interfaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At startup Linux uses some configuration file to assign IP-address to an interface. Each distribution has its own file dedicated for that purpose. You should consult your distribution Wiki on the topic of how to set an IP-address at startup.

In general it is an administrative task (i.e. should not be configured dynamically via some custom program), but if you really want to do it in your C/C++ program, then you should parse the network configuration file and place there the address you want to assign at startup.